# d3.js dendogram how to add links to leaf nodes and change colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, d3.js

I'm building this dendogram with D3.js and I'm fairly new to this so I'm having some trouble finding out how I'd add URLs to the leaf nodes (Ideally if I could use a python dictionary or a list to tell d3 which leaf nodes have which links that'd be perfect) and also how to change the colors of the nodes (text and circle) according to a variable I have in my database (I'd prefer to add this info via an auxiliary list or dictionary as well).

I'll leave my code and a picture of the actual dendogram.

Thank you so much!

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>   
    var width = 2000;  
    var height = 3000;  
    var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()        
        .size([height, width-800]);  
    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()        
        .projection (function(d) { return [d.y, d.x];});  
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")        
        .attr("width",width)        
        .attr("height",height)        
        .append("g")        
        .attr("transform","translate(100,0)");  
    d3.json("{% url 'build_json' %}", function(error, root){        
        var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);        
        var links = cluster.links(nodes);        
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")              
            .data(links)              
            .enter().append("path")              
            .attr("class","link")              
            .attr("d", diagonal);         
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")              
            .data(nodes)              
            .enter().append("g")              
            .attr("class","node")              
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });        
        node.append("circle")              
            .attr("r", 4.5);        
        node.append("text")              
            .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
            .attr("dy", 3)              
            .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })             
            .text( function(d){ return d.name;});  
}); 
</script>
```

```css
    .node circle {        
        fill: #fff;       
        stroke: steelblue;       
        stroke-width: 1.5px;  
    }  
    .node {       
        font: 20px sans-serif;  
    }  
    .link {       
        fill: none;       
        stroke: #ccc;       
        stroke-width: 1.5px;  
    }
```

```html
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

[image: dendogram]